How to prove that $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: 1 \leq \|x\| \leq 2\}$ is connected without convexity
I'm trying to understand if $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: 1 \leq \|x\| \leq 2\}$ is connected. For reference, this problem is from Jerold Marsden and Michael Hoffman's Classical Elementary Analysis (2nd edition) and is found in the exercises for chapter 3.
I'm fairly certain that this set is connected just by visualization in at most $\mathbb{R}^3$, so I've based my proof attempts around this.
My first attempt was to prove path-connectedness since it implies connectedness. To do this I decided there were two cases for two points $x,y\in A$: $\|x\| > 1$ and $\|y\| \geq 1$ and $\|x\| = 1 = \|y\|$.
For the first case I constructed the path $\phi:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $\phi(t) = (1-t)x + ty$ since this is clearly continuous and can be easily shown to be inside of the ball with radius $2$; however, I became stuck when trying to prove that this line will also have a magnitude of at least $1$. I'm not sure if I'm completely overlooking something simple in proving this or if this is more challenging than it appears.
I have even gotten stuck on the second case since the ring of radius 1 seems to be an obvious choice for a path if $\|x\| = 1 = \|y\|$, but I can't figure out how to prove that the ring of radius $1$ is continuous.
I'm open to other approaches as well, as I've considered proof by contradiction since intuitively it seems like I shouldn't be able to separate a subset of the connected ball of radius $2$, but I don't know where to start on this approach.
Very sorry if this is a simple question, but I'm very new to topology. Thanks for your help

The path $\phi(t)$ is a straight line connecting the two points. This won't always be within $A$. For example, in the case $n=2$, take $x=(-2,0)$ and $y=(2,0)$. Then, $\phi$ passes through the origin, so is of course not contained within $A$.

It is clearly not true for $n=1$.
For $n\ge 2$, pick distinct $x_1,x_2 \in A$, and let $L$ be a two dimensional subspace containing $x_1,x_2$. Let $v_1,v_2$ be orthogonal unit vectors spanning $L$, and define $\phi:[1,2] \times \mathbb{R} \to A \cap L$ by $\phi(r,\theta) = (r \cos \theta) v_1 +  (r \sin \theta) v_2$. Note that $\phi$ is continuous and surjective. Suppose $x_k = \phi(r_k, \theta_k)$, then the path
$\gamma(t)=\phi((1-t)r_1+tr_2, (1-t)\theta_1+ t \theta_2)$ connects $x_1,x_2$.
In particular, $A$ is path connected, hence connected.

Wow! Thank you for answering both cases. I got tunnel vision and didn't even consider counterexamples. Thank you so much for opening my eyes to this

As mentioned in the comments, the annulus is not convex. Take diametrically opposite points: if you draw the line segment, you will pass through the origin, which is not in the annulus.

Option 1.
A circle is connected; by dilation and translation, it suffices to prove that the unit circle $S^1$ centered at the origin is connected. To do this, just observe that $S^1$ is the image of $f:[0,2\pi]\to\Bbb{R}^2$, $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$, i.e $S^1$ is the image of a connected set (interval) under a continuous map.
Next, to show your annulus is path-connected, take any two points $x,y$. Let $\xi=2\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and $\eta=2\frac{y}{\|y\|}$ (i.e $\xi,\eta$ are the points on the outer circle obtained by going radially outwards from $x$ and $y$ respectively). So, if you want an explicit path from $x$ to $y$, then go $x\to \xi\to\eta\to y$ (straight line outwards, followed by a circular arc, followed by a straight line inwards). These are three continuous functions which can be pieced together to give a continuous function lying completely in the annulus and which joins $x$ to $y$.

Option 2.
Another approach to show connectedness of an annulus is to consider the map $f:[r_1,r_2]\times[0,2\pi]\to\Bbb{R}^2$ given as $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. The domain is a rectangle, so connected, and $f$ is continuous, so the image, which is the closed annulus of radii $r_1\leq r_2$, is also connected.

More generally, you can mimic the argument in option 1 to show that every sphere $S^n\subset\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $n\geq 1$ is connected (any two points can be joined by an arc of a great circle). Next, generalizing option 2, the map $f:[r_1,r_2]\times S^n\to\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ defined as $f(r,\omega):= r\omega$ is a continuous map from a connected set (it is a product of connected sets) so the image is connected. This image is a (closed) annuluar region in $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ of radii $r_1\leq r_2$. So, annuli in higher dimensions are connected as well (and same argument for the open annuli as well, by replacing $[r_1,r_2]$ with $(r_1,r_2)$).

Thanks for the answer. I appreciate your depth in spite of my now very obvious oversight for the case of n=1

Let us first prove that the unit sphere $S^{n-1} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:\|x\| = 1\}$ is pathwise connected. Your idea was to consider the linear path $\gamma_{x,y} : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n, \gamma_{x,y}(t) = (1-t)x+ty$ which connects two points $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$. It does not give a path in $S^{n-1}$ for $x \ne y$, but it can easily be adapted provided $\gamma_{x,y}(t) \ne 0$ for all $t$. Simply take the path
$$\Gamma_{x,y}(t) = \frac{\gamma_{x,y}(t)}{\lVert \gamma_{x,y}(t) \rVert} .$$
When does $\gamma_{x,y}$ go through $0$? That is, when does
$$(1-t)x + ty = 0 \tag{1}$$
have a solution $t_0 \in [0,1]$? Clearly $t_0 = 0,1$ are no solutions, and $t_0 \in (0,1)$ is a solution of $(1)$ iff $y = \frac{t_0-1}{t_0}x$. This implies $1 = \lVert y \rVert = \frac{1-t_0}{t_0}\lVert x \rVert =  \frac{1-t_0}{t_0}$ so that we get $t_0 = \frac 1 2$ and $y = -x$.
In other words, only for antipodal points $x,y \in S^{n-1}$ we get a problem because $\Gamma_{x,y}(t)$ is undefined for $t = \frac 1 2 $.
However, if $y = -x$, we can pick any $z \in S^{n-1} \setminus \{x,y\}$. Then $x$ and $z$ are not antipodal and we get a path in $S^{n-1}$ from $x$ to $z$. Similarly we get a path from $z$ to $y$. Concatening these paths gives a path from $x$ to $y = -x$.
As a consequence also the set $A$ is pathwise connected. Indeed, each $\xi \in A$ admits a path in $A$ from $\xi$ to  $\xi' = \frac{\xi}{\lVert \xi \rVert} \in S^{n-1}$. Simply take the "radial path" $\rho_\xi(t) = \left(1-t + t\frac{1}{\lVert \xi \rVert}\right)\xi$.
For arbitrary $\xi, \eta \in A$ take paths in $A$ from $\xi$ to $\xi'$, from $\xi'$ to $\eta'$ and from $\eta'$ to $\eta$. Their concatenation is a path from $\xi$ to $\eta$.

Lemma:If $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ is a collection of connected subsets of X such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in \Lambda}U_{\alpha}\ne \emptyset$,then
$U=\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Lambda} U_{\alpha}\subset X$ is a connected subset.
proof of lemma:Suppose U is not a connected subset,then there exists a separation of U,namely O and W,since $\bigcap_{\alpha\in \Lambda}U_{\alpha}\ne \emptyset$,suppose $m\in \bigcap_{\alpha \in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}$,WLOG,let $m\in O$ and $m\notin W$,since every $U_{\alpha}$ is connected,we then obtain that for every $\alpha$,$U_{\alpha}\subset O$,then $U=\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Lambda} U_{\alpha}\subset O$,which means $U=O,W=\emptyset$,which contradicts to the definition of separation.
Let's begin our proof,
For $n=1$,obviously it's not connected.
For $n\ge2$,we can write every $x\in A$ in the form that $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$,fix $x_1=c_1,x_2=c_2,\cdots,x_{n-1}=c_{n-1}$,where $c_i\in [0,2]$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n-1$,we let
$$t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_{n-1},x_n}=\bigcup_{x_n\in\{(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}c_i^2)+x_n^2\in [1,4]\}}(c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_n)$$here $t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_{n-1}}$ is connected,since $c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_{n-1}$ are fixed constants.Then,we let $$t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-1},c_n}=\bigcup_{x_{n-1}\in\{(\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}c_i^2)+x_{n-1}^2+c_n^2\in [1,4]\}}(c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-1},c_n)$$we denote
$$t^2_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-1},x_n}=t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_{n-1},x_n}\cup t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-1},c_n}$$By lemma,$t^2_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-1},x_n}$ is connected,since $\exists x_{n-1},x_{n}$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}c_i^2+x_{n-1}^2+x_n^2\in [1,4]$,which means $t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_{n-1},x_n}\cap t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-1},c_n}\neq \emptyset$
Similarly,we denote
$$t^3_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_n}=t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-2},c_{n-1},c_n}\cup t^2_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-1},x_n}$$
$$t^4_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-3},x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_n}=t^1_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-3},c_{n-2},c_{n-1},c_n}\cup t^3_{c_1,c_2,\cdots,x_{n-2},x_{n-1},x_n}$$
$$\vdots$$
Inductively,we have
$$A=t^n_{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n}=t^1_{x_1,c_2,c_3,\cdots,c_{n-1},c_n}\cup t^{n-1}_{c_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_{n-1},x_n}$$and A is connected.
